# How to use ajax links and normal links in the same JSF dataTable (IceFaces)

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, commandlink, ace-datatable

IceFaces 3.3
JSF 2.1

I'm trying to build a table with "uploaded files". I need an ajax link to delete each row. Not a problem.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{entityBoundFileBean.downloadFile(entityBoundFile.id)}" target="_blank">
    <h:outputText value="#{entityBoundFile.fileName}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Now, I need a link in another cell to download each file. It's a link that calls for an action of my ControllerBean.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{entityBoundFileBean.deleteFile(entityBoundFile.id)}">
    <h:outputText value="#{text['entityBoundFile.delete']}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

The problem is that, by default, those links are ajax enabled, so, the *delete* one works perfectly but not the *download* one.

I can use the f:ajax tag:

```
<h:form>
    <f:ajax event="click" disabled="true" />
```

...but it turns my delete links ajax-disable.

How can I have ajax-enabled links and ajax-disabled links in the same dataTable?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? Has anyone idea of how to acomplish what Iago asks?